# displaying random row from last 100 entries?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently displaying a random row from all the entries and that works fine.

```
SELECT * FROM $db_table where live = 1 order by rand() limit 1
```

now, i'd like to limit it to the last 100 entries in the db.

every row in the db has an ID and a timestamp.

it's a small database, so overhead-minimization is not a priority.

thanks!

EDIT:

Still can't get it running.. I get a mysql_fetch_array error:

```
"Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource
```

Here's all of my code:

```
<?php $sql = "SELECT * FROM
(SELECT * FROM $db_table ORDER BY $datetime DESC LIMIT 100)
ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

echo "".$row['familyname']."";

} ?>
```

Thanks again!

Comment: You should do an echo mysql_error() before your while() loop to determine what's wrong with your query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I came up with off the top of my head. I've tested it and it works in SQLite, so you shouldn't have much trouble with MySQL. The only change was that SQLite's random function is random() not rand():

```
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT * FROM $db_table ORDER BY $timestamp DESC LIMIT 100)
ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1
```

Comment: What exactly does ORDER by rand() do? There seem to be a lot of complaints on mysql.com's forums about performance problems using this method of randomization, though those might be from poorly designed queries or databases.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I can't get it to run.. Updated the original question. Thanks again!

Comment: You need to replace $db_table with your table name. I don't know what you can replace $timestamp with. I used the MySQL command, NOW(). Also, you need to assign an alias to the outer select by putting something like "AS r1" after "DESC LIMIT 100)"

Answer (score 1):

[This page](http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/) has a pretty detailed writeup on how to optimize an `ORDER BY RAND()`-type query. It's actually too involved for me to explain adequately on SO (also, I don't fully understand some of the SQL commands used, though the general concept makes sense), but the final optimized query makes use of several optimizations:

1. First, `ORDER BY RAND()`, which uses a `filesort` algorithm on the entire table, is dropped. Instead, a query is constructed to simply generate a single random id.
2. At this stage, an `index scan` is being used, which is even less efficient than a `filesort` in many cases, so this is optimized away with a subquery.
3. The `WHERE` clause is replaced with a `JOIN` to reduce the number of rows fetched by the outer `SELECT`, and the number of times the subquery is executed, to just 1.
4. In order to account for holes in the ids (from deletions) and to ensure an equal distribution, a mapping table is created to map row numbers to ids.
5. Triggers are used to automatically update & maintain the mapping table.
6. Lastly, stored procedures are created to allow multiple rows to be selected at once. (Here, `ORDER BY` is reintroduced, but used only on the result rows.)

Here are the performance figures:

- Q1. ORDER BY RAND()
- Q2. RAND() * MAX(ID)
- Q3. RAND() * MAX(ID) + ORDER BY ID

```
   100        1.000      10.000     100.000    1.000.000
Q1  0:00.718s  0:02.092s  0:18.684s  2:59.081s  58:20.000s
Q2  0:00.519s  0:00.607s  0:00.614s  0:00.628s   0:00.637s
Q3  0:00.570s  0:00.607s  0:00.614s  0:00.628s   0:00.637s
```