# Possible to select last 100 records in MySQL, then select random 10 from those results in one query?

Tags: mysql

I need to display 10 related videos on a video page that come from the same category as that video. The problem is that there could possibly be hundreds of thousands of rows for each category so running RAND() is out of the question and I would prefer not to create a myisam table that matches my innodb table and then full text search for related.

I am not sure if my idea is possible, but I would like to select 100 of the latest rows for that category ordered by date, and then select only 10 from that set randomly.

Is this possible and could you point me in the right direction please?

Comment: You could do the initial query as a sub query/temp table query/with query as... and then surround it with a second query that orders by RAND(), limit 10. Though exactly how to code this will depend upon SQL flavour and I don't know how to do it in mysql :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [displaying random row from last 100 entries?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/766530/displaying-random-row-from-last-100-entries)

Comment: @BellevueBob Thank you, I tried searching for it here and could not find exactly what I needed. Looks like that is similar or the same as Mark's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming you have a simple table with an identity named `ID`, and you can do something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT ID, Name, VideoFile
  FROM VideoTable
  ORDER BY ID DESC
  LIMIT 100
) Derived
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

select * from 
(select * from table  ORDER BY DESC LIMIT 100)
ORDER BY    rand()
LIMIT       10